# Is there a way to inject a fake udev device?

Tags: linux, modem, udev

I have a program that talks to a specific serial device. The program tries to detect the device using udev (it checks for a specific udev variable), then it opens the device and starts communication.

I'm trying to develop a software emulator for that device. My current idea is to create a pseudoterminal (pty), symlink it into the path expected by the application, and then somehow tell udev that this device exists and should be reported. Is there a supported way of doing this kind of stuff with udev?

P.S. I know about tty0tty, but I would prefer not to mess with the kernel.

EDIT: to clarify, this is meant for production, not for development/testing.